# REST request resolution in Jersey due to ambiguous path?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a rest application based on jersey in which there are two controllers : A & B.

This is how they are created :

Controller A

```
//Root Path : 
@Path("/a/a_id")

//API -1
PUT
@Path("/b/b_id")
associateBtoA{...}
```

Controller B

```
//Root Path : 
@Path("/a/a_id/b/b_id")

various methods...
```

Now whenever i try to call the API-1 in Controller A(/a/a_id/b/b_id) as PUT - it gives 404(Resource not found).

Looks like it was getting confused between the root path for controller B& path for API 1 in controller A. When i changed the path for API 1 as below it worked.

```
//API -1
PUT
@Path("/bCHANGED/b_id")
associateBtoA{...}
```

Why is the root path in controller B being considered as a resource? It does not even have a GET,PUT,POST identifier.